# elementary save/retrieve shared preferences

Tags: android, android-edittext, sharedpreferences

My app is seems to be crashing upon entering a new activity. For now this activity only has an edit-text field that i'm trying to test my sharedpreferences skills on. I didn't make the shared preferences file yet, but i'm under the impression that it is automatically made upon accessing it. Here is logcat:

```
09-18 02:29:30.293: W/ResourceType(428): No package identifier when getting value for resource number 0x0000000a
09-18 02:29:30.303: D/AndroidRuntime(428): Shutting down VM
09-18 02:29:30.315: W/dalvikvm(428): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
09-18 02:29:30.334: E/AndroidRuntime(428): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-18 02:29:30.334: E/AndroidRuntime(428): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.mangodeveloper.mcathomie/com.mangodeveloper.mcathomie.McatActivityPlayOptions}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0xa
09-18 02:29:30.334: E/AndroidRuntime(428):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
09-18 02:29:30.334: E/AndroidRuntime(428):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
09-18 02:29:30.334: E/AndroidRuntime(428):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
09-18 02:29:30.334: E/AndroidRuntime(428):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
09-18 02:29:30.334: E/AndroidRuntime(428):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-18 02:29:30.334: E/AndroidRuntime(428):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
09-18 02:29:30.334: E/AndroidRuntime(428):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
09-18 02:29:30.334: E/AndroidRuntime(428):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-18 02:29:30.334: E/AndroidRuntime(428):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
09-18 02:29:30.334: E/AndroidRuntime(428):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
09-18 02:29:30.334: E/AndroidRuntime(428):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
09-18 02:29:30.334: E/AndroidRuntime(428):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-18 02:29:30.334: E/AndroidRuntime(428): Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0xa
09-18 02:29:30.334: E/AndroidRuntime(428):  at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:201)
09-18 02:29:30.334: E/AndroidRuntime(428):  at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2857)
09-18 02:29:30.334: E/AndroidRuntime(428):  at com.mangodeveloper.mcathomie.McatActivityPlayOptions.onCreate(McatActivityPlayOptions.java:23)
09-18 02:29:30.334: E/AndroidRuntime(428):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
09-18 02:29:30.334: E/AndroidRuntime(428):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
09-18 02:29:30.334: E/AndroidRuntime(428):  ... 11 more
```

And here is the code:

```
package com.mangodeveloper.mcathomie;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class McatActivityPlayOptions extends Activity {

    private EditText QuestionNumberEt;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_playoptions);

        QuestionNumberEt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Etnumberofquestions);
        SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("MYPREFS", 0);
        QuestionNumberEt.setText(settings.getInt("MAXROUNDSVALUE", 10));

        Button startGameButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.startgamebutton);
        startGameButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent PlayIntent = new Intent (McatActivityPlayOptions.this, McatActivityGame.class);
                PlayIntent.putExtra("MAXROUNDS", Integer.parseInt(QuestionNumberEt.getText().toString()));
                startActivity(PlayIntent);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("MYPREFS", 0);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
        editor.putInt("MAXROUNDSVALUE", Integer.parseInt(QuestionNumberEt.getText().toString()));
        editor.commit();

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is here:

```
QuestionNumberEt.setText(settings.getInt("MAXROUNDSVALUE", 10));
```

You are setting text to `10` (`int`), not `"10"` (`String`). The `int` value is interpreted as a resource ID (0xA, from your error log, is 10 in decimal), so it's trying to find a resource matching ID 10--which doesn't exist.

Try one of the following:

```
QuestionNumberEt.setText(settings.getInt("MAXROUNDSVALUE", 10) + "");
// OR
QuestionNumberEt.setText(String.valueOf(settings.getInt("MAXROUNDSVALUE", 10)));
```

Comment: so you're saying that the set text method can only set strings?

Comment: Strings and resource IDs. For example, if you had, in [`strings.xml`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html), `<string name='foo'>Some Text</string>`, then you could do `view.setText(R.string.foo)`. Otherwise, yes, it must be a string (or other derivative of [`CharSequence`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/CharSequence.html)).

Comment: thanks, just tested your solution and it worked. i knew my question should have some simple solution. i'm just bummed to have had to ask it. :I